Locating the temp sensor on motor controller
I am helping my neighbor with fixing his out of warranty EV UTV. I have narrowed it down to a faulty temp sensor.
-Controller: Curtis 1234SE 72vdc 3Ph VFD.
Fault code:15.
What would a label next to it likely be?
I see a TH1, it is a red SMD, numbers are 473.
Controller works after cleaning and vacuum desiccation but randomly throws a code for severe under temp of heat sink. It is 72F outside and controller is not overheating either.
Unit had water damage and worked before clean up but goes into “limp” mode.

Are you sure the problem is a faulty temperature sensor and not something that's actually causing bad temperature excursions? If you can, you might want to look around it in operation with an infrared temperature sensor or so. Specifically, water damage is just as likely, if not more so, to cause a real problem that is pushing the temperatures up than just damaging a temperature sensor.

If I were designing that PCB, the temperature sensor would likely be under one or all of the heat sinks and thermally bonded to them. They might also be integrated in one or more of the critical ICs which are likely to overheat.

Thank you for your response, I have verified any overtemp conditions or abnormalities with a Flir infrared camera. Once the heat sink has warmed up to 100F, the code clears and operates normally. The heat sink is a 5lb block of aluminum that makes up the base of the chassis.

The "TH" is centrally located on the PCB and probably is a thermistor. '473' suggests that it is 47kΩ at 25°C. That's inadequate to fully specify the part, but one might get close by using the part dimensions and picking a likely \$\beta\$. However...֫
It is very unlikely that water damage would cause the thermistor to fail. It's more likely (like close to 100%) that there are remnants of water damage that you have not remediated.
I can see that the board has not been properly cleaned. If water has gotten between the PCB and the heat sink it will require a bunch of work to get it apart, cleaned and the thermal compound properly replaced so it will function without damaging itself. But that would be the right way to do it.
If you feel like gambling a bit, get some 99% isopropanol and a toothbrush and carefully scrub the top of the board board to get rid of all those white deposits. Pay particular attention to places where there are leads of components with spaces underneath them as well as to the area around the sensor. Allow it to thoroughly dry (I'd suggest overnight) before attempting to apply power.

Thank you for your response, I had removed all boards on ann esd mat, cleaned with IPA, dried in oven and a few hours in a vacuum chamber. The residue on there now is silicone conformal coating. New thermal transfer paste has been applied.
